# How do I bypass Only use parentheses for ternary expressions with complex conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

My code looks like this:

```
def redirector
  # :nocov:
  unless ENV["URL"]
    return "https://google.com"
  end
  # :nocov:

  redirect_url = (request.original_fullpath.include? "404") ? root_path : request.original_url
  param_object = { redirect: redirect_url }

  ENV["URL"] + "?" + param_object.to_param
end
```

Is there a better way to write this?

```
redirect_url = (request.original_fullpath.include? "404") ? root_path : request.original_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
redirect_url = request.original_fullpath.include?("404") ? root_path : request.original_url
```

Or even:

```
redirect_url = if request.original_fullpath.include? "404"
  root_path
else
  request.original_url
end
```

You get the warning about parentheses, because your condition is simple. Complex condition would look like this:

```
foo = (bar && baz) ? a : b
```

[Check out the doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/TernaryParentheses).